# Can I "shape" the sound of words spoken by Pepper with Phonetic transcription?

Tags: speech-processing, pepper

I am using Aldebaran/Softbank Robotics Pepper with Choregraphe software. There are some loan words in my dialogs. When Pepper say these words they often don't sound natural.

e.g. the german word **Demenz** (eng: **dementia**) The first **e** is to long. I imagine some synax like that `De[0.5]menz` or phonetic transcription `[deˈmɛnʦ]`.

Is this possible?

Comment: what does`loan words`mean?

Comment: @jsotola Is "foreign word" a better translation? I mean words used by experts not "normal" people.

Comment: "Loan Word" is the proper phrase for what the OP is talking about. It means a word which has come into one language from another language. For example, in French there was a word (among others), "la Girlfriend" which came from English. The French government was not amused. I'm a native US English speaker, and I studied languages in college (40 years ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to tweak the ponetic proncunciation, see [the documentation here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-tuto.html?highlight=lhp#inserting-phonetic-text):

```
tts.setLanguage("English")
tts.say("\\toi=lhp\\‘zi.R+o&U \\toi=orth\\")
# Same as
tts.say("zero")
```